# How to force processing to properly deal a negative value for movement?

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I am working on a "golf" game in processing for school and I can get the ball itself to move, but it only moves properly in the Up and Left direction. And by properly I mean it only applies the friction and moves the appropriate amount. In every direction other than up and left it moves a very short and abrupt amount.

I have attached my code for anyone who can help and I have tried to comment it to the best of my ability because I know my thought process probably isn't great in this.

```
final float MIN_SPEED = 0.5; //Minimum speed the ball can be travelling
final float FRICTION = 0.98;
final float BALL_SIZE = 14.0;

float holeX;
float holeY;
float ballX = 250;
float ballY = 250;
float ballSpeedX;
float ballSpeedY;
float ballDistanceX;
float ballDistanceY;
float xVelocity = 0;
float yVelocity = 0;
boolean isHole = false;
boolean move = false;


void setup(){
  size(500,500);
}
/* Function to set initial X & Y Velocities as well as move to true when the mouse is clicked and released */
void mouseClicked(){
   xVelocity = ballDistanceX * 0.04;
   yVelocity = ballDistanceY * 0.04;
   move = true;
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE); // initializes the ball to the center
    if(move == false){ // draws a line from the cursor to the ball when it is not moving
      fill(255);
      line(mouseX, mouseY, ballX, ballY);
      ballDistanceX = mouseX - ballX;
      ballDistanceY = mouseY - ballY;
    }
else if(move == true){ //When the mouse has been clicked, moves the ball the opposite direction of where the click was
      xVelocity *= FRICTION; // applies friction to slow the ball down
      yVelocity *= FRICTION;
        if (ballX >= 0 && ballY >= 0){
      ballX -= xVelocity; // changes the position of ballX
      ballY -= yVelocity;
      ellipse(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE); // redraws the ball in its new position
        }
        if (ballX >= 0 && ballY <= 0){
      ballX -= xVelocity;
      ballY += yVelocity;
      ellipse(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
        }
        if (ballX <= 0 && ballY >= 0){
      ballX += xVelocity;
      ballY -= yVelocity;
      ellipse(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
        }
        if (ballX < 0 && ballY < 0){
      ballX += xVelocity;
      ballY += yVelocity;
      ellipse(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
        }            
              if (xVelocity < MIN_SPEED || yVelocity < MIN_SPEED) { // Once the ball slows down enough it resets move to false
                move = false;
              }
    }
        if (xVelocity < MIN_SPEED || yVelocity < MIN_SPEED) {
          move = false;
        }
  }
```

If there is anything I can do to clarify it or make it easier to understand just let me know!

Comment: Rather than `if() if() if() if()` use `if() else if() else if() else`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done on identifying the part with that's causing the problem.

You're checking `if(xVelocity < MIN_SPEED || yVelocity < MIN_SPEED)`.

The issue with this is you're only checking if x or y velocity are positive and within a small threshold (0.0 - 0.5).

If velocity is your vector, what you want to check is the vector's magnitude. Be sure to check out [Daniel Shiffman's Vectors chapter on Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/) or his youtube videos on a wee bit of linear algebra.
The idea is the vector's magnitude is the vector's length. The bigger the line, the bigger the vector (velocity in your case), regardless of the direction (positive or negative x,y components). It's simply using the Euclidean distance (Pythagoras theorem)

Here's a tweaked version of your code with the variables not required to run removed. Also, you didn't really need that `while` loop: `draw()` is already your infinite loop to update within:

```
final float MIN_SPEED = 0.5; //Minimum speed the ball can be travelling
final float FRICTION = 0.98;
final float BALL_SIZE = 14.0;

float ballX = 250;
float ballY = 250;
float ballDistanceX;
float ballDistanceY;
float xVelocity = 0;
float yVelocity = 0;
boolean move = false;


void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}
/* Function to set initial X & Y Velocities as well as move to true when the mouse is clicked and released */
void mouseClicked() {
  xVelocity = ballDistanceX * 0.04;
  yVelocity = ballDistanceY * 0.04;
  move = true;
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE); // initializes the ball to the center

  if (move == false) { // draws a line from the cursor to the ball when it is not moving

    fill(255);
    line(mouseX, mouseY, ballX, ballY);
    ballDistanceX = mouseX - ballX;
    ballDistanceY = mouseY - ballY;

  } else { //When the mouse has been clicked, moves the ball the opposite direction of where the click was

      xVelocity *= FRICTION; // applies friction to slow the ball down
      yVelocity *= FRICTION;
      ballX -= xVelocity; // changes the position of ballX by subtracting velocity
      ballY -= yVelocity;

  }

  ellipse(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE); // redraws the ball in its new position

  float mag = sqrt(xVelocity*xVelocity + yVelocity*yVelocity);
  if(mag < MIN_SPEED){
    move = false;
  }
}
```

You can also run the code as p5.js sketch bellow:

```js
const MIN_SPEED = 0.5; //Minimum speed the ball can be travelling
const FRICTION = 0.98;
const BALL_SIZE = 14.0;

var ballX = 250;
var ballY = 250;
var ballDistanceX;
var ballDistanceY;
var xVelocity = 0;
var yVelocity = 0;
var move = false;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
}
/* Function to set initial X & Y Velocities as well as move to true when the mouse is clicked and released */
function mouseClicked() {
  xVelocity = ballDistanceX * 0.04;
  yVelocity = ballDistanceY * 0.04;
  move = true;
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE); // initializes the ball to the center
  
  if (move == false) { // draws a line from the cursor to the ball when it is not moving
    
    fill(255);
    line(mouseX, mouseY, ballX, ballY);
    ballDistanceX = mouseX - ballX;
    ballDistanceY = mouseY - ballY;
    
  } else { //When the mouse has been clicked, moves the ball the opposite direction of where the click was
    
      xVelocity *= FRICTION; // applies friction to slow the ball down
      yVelocity *= FRICTION;
      ballX -= xVelocity; // changes the position of ballX by subtracting velocity
      ballY -= yVelocity;
      
  }
  
  ellipse(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE); // redraws the ball in its new position
  
  var mag = sqrt(xVelocity*xVelocity + yVelocity*yVelocity);
  if(mag < MIN_SPEED){
    move = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great! Be sure to checkout Daniel Shiffman's tutorial: linear algebra is essential for gamedev. Also checkout Processing's [PVector](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) class: it implements magnitude (via `mag()`) and magnitude squared (`magSq()`) already, not mention `add()` and other goodies that will greatly simplify your code

Comment: I definitely will be doing some more research but for right now, I am super limited as to what I'm allowed to use within Processing!